# Proving a combinatorics equality: $\binom{r}{r} + \binom{r+1}{r} + \cdots + \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

How to prove the following? Should I use induction or something else?

> Let $n$ and $r$ be positive integers with $n \ge r$. Prove that
>   $$\binom{r}{r} + \binom{r+1}{r} + \cdots + \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}.$$

*Attempted start:*

Basis step: ${\binom{1}{1}} = {\binom{2}{2}}$ true.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Fix $r$ and prove by induction. Initial: $n=r$: So $\binom r r=\binom{r+1}{r+1}$. Then prove if true for $n$, true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a combinatorial proof.  Consider the problem of choosing $r+1$ numbers from $1,2,\ldots,n+1$, where repetition is not allowed and order is not important.

- First do it the obvious way.  The number of ways is the RHS.
- Then do it by initially choosing the largest of the $r+1$ numbers.

See if you can fill in the details.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am not getting. The largest of the $r+1$ numbers can be chosen in $n+1-r$ ways. Then the number of choices for second largest depends on the first choice, we do we do then?

Comment: Don't choose the second largest, choose all the others simultaneously.  The number of choices will depend on the value of the largest.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\binom ab+\binom a{b+1}&=\binom{a+1}{b+1}\\
\Rightarrow \binom ab&=\binom{a+1}{b+1}-\binom a{b+1}\end{align}$$

Hence 
$$\begin{align}
\binom ir&=\binom {i+1}{r+1}-\binom i{r+1}\\
\sum_{i=r}^n\binom ir&=\sum_{i=r}^n\binom {i+1}{r+1}-\sum_{i=r}^n\binom i{r+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=r+1}^{n+1}\binom {i}{r+1}-\sum_{i=r+1}^n\binom i{r+1}\\
&=\binom {n+1}{r+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$