# How to prove ${\sum_{k=0}^r} {{n+k}\choose{k}}={{n+r+1}\choose{r}}$?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to prove
$${\sum_{k=0}^r} {{n+k}\choose{k}}={{n+r+1}\choose{r}}$$
with combination formula.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031887/do-i-use-induction-or-is-there-another-way-to-prove-binomrr-binomr1r