# Let n and r be positive integers with n ≥ r.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let n and r be positive integers with n ≥ r. Prove that
>   ($\tfrac{r}{r}$) + ($\tfrac{r + 1}{r}$) + • • • + ($\frac{n}{r}$) = ($\tfrac{n + 1}{r + 1}$)

I was trying to do this, but I'm keep over thinking and confusing myself with this question. How can I prove this equation? Needing help since not use to discrete math.(getting confuse, if I should be focusing on the probability or combination)
also how can I remove the line from the fraction(this line: -)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032020/how-to-prove-sum-k-0r-nk-choosek-nr1-chooser

Comment: $n\choose k$ is "n\choose k"

Comment: @labbhattacharjee oh, ok thank you, I didn't get that result when I typed it in the search box. sorry for posting the same thing.

Comment: Type "\${n \choose k}\$" to get ${n \choose k}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial proof.  The right hand side is the number of ways to choose $r+1$ elements from the set $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$.

In how many ways can we choose $r+1$ elements from $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ such that the largest element chosen is $n+1$?  The remaining $r$ elements must be chosen from the first $n$ elements, and this can be done in ${n \choose r}$ ways.  Similarly, the number of ways to choose $r+1$ elements from $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ such that the largest element chosen is $r+1$ is the number of ways to choose $r$ elements from the first $r$ elements, which is ${r \choose r}$.  Thus, the left hand side also counts the number of ways to choose $r+1$ elements from the set $\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$.  The largest element chosen must be at least $r+1$, so the first term in the left hand side is ${r \choose r}$.